# Raspberry Pi Apache - Forbidden No Permission error

Tags: apache, server, raspberry-pi, ip, localhost

I am running an apache 2.4.10 server from my raspberry pi. When I go to the local ip address of my raspberry Pi, I get the following error:
[image]

I want the site hosted on the server to be visible to anyone on the web. Is there a way to do that?

**ANY help will be appreciated**

**Thank You** for your time.

Comment: So, what _are_ the permissions of the file system objects the http server tries to read? Hint: look into the file system and the http servers error log file...

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to all this stuff

Comment: The configuration of the apache http server defines where the log files are written and what part of the local file system is used as a base for the service. We cannot tell you these details, only you have access to your system.

Comment: I followed [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server) tutorial. Does that tell you where it is stored?

Comment: That tutorial is _totally_ outdated. I suggest you start reading the documentation of the tools you use. The apache http server's documentation is, as typical for OpenSource projects, of excellent quality and comes with good examples. You will find the local configuration under `/etc/apache2`, the documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167860/discussion-between-marmadukeandbob-and-arkascha).